# How do I remove the percent sign?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which has the index, names of suppliers and how much profit each supplier made in each of the 4 cities - Delhi, Mumbai, Hyderabad, and Jaipur. Check the image for reference.

[Head of the dataset and the percent sign remaining even after the function has been applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Twtl.png)

When I try to remove the percent sign from the end of the profit values using a lambda function and apply function, the percent sign still remains.

```
df.head()
df_cities = df[['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Jaipur', 'Hyderabad']].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
df_cities.head()
```

Even if I try -2 as the end slicing index int the lambda function, there's absolutely no difference. It works when I try to remove the first digit value but there's no difference when I try to access it from the end. Why is that happening?

I also tried replacing the percent sign with nothing using the replace function but even then nothing happened. How do I remove the percent sign at the end of the values?

Comment: @Ch3steR What do you mean by `without last rows` ?

Comment: @Ch3steR What you're doing is going to return that since you're taking all but the last row of the `Series` . Could you check my post? I'm using `x.str` before slicing

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Your post got deleted somehow but it works! Why do I have to include .str in some cases?

Comment: Apparently, some posts are missing from the comments section. Per @Ch3steR's suggesion, I've changed it from `apply` to `agg` and undeleted my post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot

```py
df_cities = df[['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Jaipur', 'Hyderabad']].agg(lambda x: x.str[:-1])
```